# How to pass multiple props to makeStyles() with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I read about how to pass 1 prop to `makeStyle()` here and came up with the following approach, for my task of passing in *2* props. But error reads `cannot find name 'props'`. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
const Foo = ({ bar, color, backgroundColor }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({color, backgroundColor});
  ...
};

type Props = {
  color: string
  backgroundColor: string
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    ...BaseTheme(theme),
    main: {
      color: `${props.color}`,
      backgroundColor: `${props.backgroundColor}`,
    },
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be a function with `props` as a parameter for the `main` property.

```jsx
type Props = {
  color: string
  backgroundColor: string
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    ...BaseTheme(theme),
    main: (props: Props) => ({
      color: `${props.color}`,
      backgroundColor: `${props.backgroundColor}`,
    }),
  }),
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. however there's still an error ```Property 'color' does not exist on type '{}'.```. I've edited the question to include the calling component. Maybe I've done something wrong there?

Comment: `main: (props: Props) => ({.......blaaahh......})` is this working?

Comment: still not working. I will update the question with a codesandbox link and try again.

Comment: It did work with your second suggestion once I removed the line of ```...BaseTheme(theme),```. Thank you!